# Can I format my validation strings with relevant info in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, validation, kohana

I've noticed in Kohana 3 these error messages provided by default.

```
return array(
    'not_empty' => ':field must not be empty.',
);
```

Obviously, `:field` is replaced with the field name.

Now I am validating an image upload. Obviously, I'm allowing only JPG, JPEG, GIF & PNG.

I have an error message set up like so.

```
return array(
    'photo' => array(
        'Upload::type' => 'You must upload an image file (JPG, JPEG, GIF, PNG)'
    )
);
```

I also use Kohana's validation helper like so.

```
$input->rules('photo', array(
'Upload::type' => array('Upload::type' => array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'))
));
```

Is there a way I can use those accepted extensions in my error string, perhaps like...

```
return array(
    'photo' => array(
        'Upload::type' => 'You can only upload files of :types'
    )
);
```

Comment: Your last code example will work as is, you just need to use `:param1` instead of `:types`.

Comment: Your code has an error, the array of types should be wrapped in an array.

Comment: @shadowhand I was following [Kerkness's example](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=validation). Are you saying it should be `array('Upload::type' => array(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif')))` ?

Comment: Correct. See [Adding Rules](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/security.validation) of the docs, there is a note about `in_array` that also applies to `Upload::type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can access the parameters with :param1 :param2 etc

```
'error' => 'You can only upload files of :param1, :param2, :param3'
```

I guess this doesn't work so well with variable amounts of parameters =(

A possible solution would be to use a callback as an alias to the rule, then take the list of allowed formats and send them to the message manually using implode().

ex:

```
public function valid_type(Validate $array, $field, $formats)
{
    $params = $formats;
    array_unshift($params, $array[$field]);
    if ( ! call_user_func_array(array('Upload', 'type'), $params))
    {
        $array->error($field, 'Upload::type', array('types' => $formats));
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I add a `,` as first argument of `implode()`?

Comment: yeah, sorry about that =P it also looks like Kohana does the implode() automatically so you could leave that out (I think) but the rest of the example is good IMO

Comment: On second thought, it seems that Upload::type() takes an array of valid types, so the example biakeveron wrote actually works as intended. My example is for rules that take a variable amount of parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Kohana [has](http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/classes/kohana/validate.php#L1047) this feature "out of the box" :)

So, you should add something like this:

```
// messages/validate.php
return array(
   'upload::type' => ':field should be one of the following types: [:param1]', 
);
```

Comment: Will that display the first param only though?

Comment: Yes. This example means that you use rule as described in question (one param for file types available). Kohana will automatically convert array to string with implode() function.

Comment: Remember that your first parameter is an array, so it is treated as a single parameter, not multiple.